# Disabling Local stream on Remote Side after Call is connected via WebRtc in Android

Tags: webrtc, webrtc-android

I'm trying to isolate video and audio and am able to control the video feed from the caller side, however, unable to turn off the local video stream on the remote side since its an audio call. Any suggestions on how to isolate the video and audio feeds. It doesn't work just by removing the streams by getting the `getStream`.